# Tornado: async calls and DB caching

Tags: python, cache, tornado

```
import tornado.web
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import psycopg2
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class LevelHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
        self.conn_string = "credentials_here"
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(self.conn_string)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def get(self, word):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'bin/phantomjs')
        driver.get(url="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/%s" % word)
        is_word_cached = self.check_cache(word)
        if is_word_cached:
            response = {'level': is_word_cached[0][0]}
        elif self.check_word_404(driver):
            response = {'level': "This word wasn't found"}
        else:
            try:
                level = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//span[@class='def-info']/span[contains(@title,'A1-C2')]")
                level = level.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                level = "The word level isn't known"
            self.write_cache(word, level)
            response = {'level': level}

        self.write(response)

    def check_cache(self, word):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT level FROM eng_level WHERE word = '{0}'".format(word))
        records = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return records

    def write_cache(self, word, level):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO eng_level (word, level) values (%s, %s)", (word, level,))
        self.cursor.execute("COMMIT")

    def check_word_404(self, driver):
        try:
            return driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//h1[contains(text(),'404. Page not found.')]")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/([A-Za-z]+)", LevelHandler)
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(str(sys.argv[1]))
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The idea is to fetch the word complexity from a dictionary. I use Selenium and XPath to do this, but once a word is fetched from the external HTML I store it in the database as a cache.

**Questions:**

- Is everything asynchronous here?
- I'm only 1.5 times faster: the average response from the external website is `4s` and from Postgres cache `2.5s`. Can I do better?

Comment: The dictionary website isn't using much JavaScript, so even with it disabled I see content - do you even need Selenium? I'd assume that without it and just fetching and parsing raw HTML you should be faster (and consume fewer resources).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.This handler isn't asynchronous.

The easiest way to accomplish this with tornado is to make a coroutine like so:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, word):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'bin/phantomjs')
    yield driver.get(url="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/%s" % word)
    is_word_cached = self.check_cache(word)
    if is_word_cached:
        response = {'level': is_word_cached[0][0]}
    elif self.check_word_404(driver):
        response = {'level': "This word wasn't found"}
    else:
        try:
            level = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//span[@class='def-info']/span[contains(@title,'A1-C2')]")
            level = level.text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            level = "The word level isn't known"
        self.write_cache(word, level)
        response = {'level': level}

    self.write(response)
```

The main thing is to decorate the get method with @gen.coroutine and then have a yield statement in the blocking line, in your case the fetching of the data. [Documentation here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html)

2. You can store the cache in a in-memory database like Redis, Memcached, in plain Python or in a pickle.

Comment: You marked `get` method with `@gen.asynchronous` annotation. In post you are referring to `@gen.coroutine`.  I assume `@gen.asynchronous` is a  typo, isn't it?

Comment: You're right that was a typo. It should be @gen.coroutine